# How to add label to image?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, label

Hi I used this line of code to see the format of images in mnist dataset:

```
print(mnsit.load_data())
```

The output is this:

```
(array([[[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    ...,
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]],

   [[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    ...,
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]],

   [[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    ...,
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]],

   ...,

   [[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    ...,
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]],

   [[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    ...,
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]],

   [[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    ...,
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]]], dtype=uint8), array([5, 0, 4, ..., 5, 6, 8], dtype=uint8))
```

The main array contains an array at the end. This array is a set of labels that I give to input of a neural network.

Now I need to add an array of labels at the end of images to create a dataset like mnist dataset. Are there functions I can use to do this? I tried append and insert but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like that:

```
dataset = [image_array, label_array]
```

That creates an list with the two array as a elements.